# Error page in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http

My 404.html contains:

```
<img class="img-responsive center-block" src="Images/error404.png"/>
```

My Web.config in the project folder contains:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
     <remove statusCode="404"/>
     <error statusCode="404" path="404.html" responseMode="File"/>
</httpErrors>
```

I can access image through `http://localhost:53870/Images/error404.png` in browser.

Image in 404.html is loading when i call it directly

```
localhost:53870/404.html
```

Or when i call

```
http://localhost:53870/NonexistentController
```

Image in 404.html ISN'T loading when i call something like this

```
http://localhost:53870/Home/NonexistentAction
```

[image]

Comment: add a slash to the front of the `src`: `<img class="img-responsive center-block" src="/Images/error404.png"/>`

Comment: @Liam THANK YOU !!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a backslash at the start of the image path.

Change:

```
<img class="img-responsive center-block" src="Images/error404.png"/>
```

To:

```
<img class="img-responsive center-block" src="/Images/error404.png"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In razor files, you may take advantage of the `~` operator.`~` will return the virtual root path.

`<img class="img-responsive center-block" src="~/Images/error404.png"/>`

With this, Your image src value will be correct irrespective of which sub folder/path you are in.

Comment: I've never understood the point of this. Flat out HTML does the exact same thing with a starting `/`. Why Microsoft added this as well I'll never know